# Mail Munch: paste the code right before the </head> tag on every page?

Tags: html, page

I want add Mail Munch in our website and they say that I have to paste the code on every page. How can do this? In CMS>static block>footer links don't work cause this is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the corresponding css/js in `<theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` and it will add that js/css to all head of frontend pages
.For more details read this article on magento devdocs -
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css

Answer (score 0):

if Magento 2 go Content -> Configuration -> select edit -> Under HTML Head there is Scripts and Style Sheets box for that